# Select part of data

Tags: sql, oracle

probably this is an easy one but I need your help.
I have a table with data like these:

```
   NAME       VAL1  
135.name1    value1  
135.name2    value2  
135.name3    value3
```

If I wanted to select the data in the column NAME I would do something like this:

```
select s.NAME
  FROM MY_TABLE s
where s.SCHEDULE_NAME like '135.%'

    NAME        
  135.name1      
  135.name2    
  135.name3
```

But I want to select the data in column NAME but without the '135.'
Notice that 135 is not a constant. It can be for example '34567.'. So it can be more digits.
Is it possible? I like to get this:

```
 NAME        
 name1      
 name2    
 name3
```

Comment: Do you want to remove `135.` or you just want to select values, which do not have `135.` at the beginning of a string?

Comment: remove the 135. (or the number, which i Know)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for this:-

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('135.name1', '^135.') FROM Table;
```

and for your case:-

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '^135.') FROM My_Table;
```

or try this:-

```
SELECT REPLACE('135.name1','135.','') COL1 FROM Table;
```

**EDIT:-**

To make it more dyanamic you may try this:-

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '^\d+\.') FROM My_Table;
```

Comment: That's it. Just a small correction : SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '^135.') FROM My_Table;

Comment: Yes absolutely. I have to wait until I can accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: This is good, but the problem with the solution is that it is statically looking for `135.` when @Nianios is going to need it to be more dynamic. The Regex is more appropriately `^\d+\.` to remove the leading numeric characters + the `.`.

Comment: Yet another option: `SELECT LTRIM('135.name1','135.') COL1 FROM Table;`

Comment: @neoistheone:- Yes thanks. I was about to update that too. Thanks for the suggestion. Updated my answer as well!!!

Comment: THe 135 is dynamic yes so the correct query is SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name, l_id) FROM My_Table; where l_id:^ & myId & .